# can somebody give solution to my bootstrap popover problem here?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to make an e-commerce web page with bootstrap 4. I want to have my product image show a popup for its description with bootstrap popover. But it won't show. I even erase all my code and tried to use the starter template from bootstrap, and still not worked.

here's my popover code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

and here's my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.example-popover').popover({
        container: 'body'
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `example-popover` class name in your button it will works

```js
 $('.example-popover').popover({
        container: 'body'
    })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger example-popover" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
```